# Unit testing with bazel and containers

Tags: containers, bazel

I'm trying to understand how to do testing the right way when working with bazel and containers. An application should be specified as an image in the form:

```
py_library(
    name = "mylib",
    ...
)

py_test(
    name = "mylib_test",
    ...
)

py3_image(
    name = "helloimage",
    srcs = ["hello.py"],
    main = "hello.py",
    deps [
        ":mylib",
    ]
)
```

This setup is far from ideal, since unit tests should ideally run inside the same container base image, i.e. they should run within the container and not the dev's local environment. How have are people dealing with this, since this seems like a fundamental problem with Bazel's container setup?